# Create P2P connections with Wi-Fi Direct in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, p2p, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I want to use Wifi Direct p2p in my flutter project. When I searched about it, I got to know that it can be done using native APIs easily. Is there any Dart support to use p2p? Or I must have to go for native languages?

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at this package [flutter_p2p.](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_p2p) It's a Wifi Direct plugin for flutter and as of now only available for android.

Comment: I already have seen it. But there are some bugs in the plugins. Even the example app is not working properly.

Comment: Can we share files using p2p?

Comment: yes wifi direct p2p allows you to share data between devices. Also, the package is in alpha stage so its a possibility that there would be bugs in the package.

Answer (score 0):

You can call android or ios code from flutter.
Flutter for the GUI and p2p system from android or ios.